# Multipe action="" attribute urls

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, action

I am wanting to know if you can add more than one url in the action attribute in the form element? I know a lot of people are asking that but the ones I am adding in are: a php self and a mailto action. This is a feedback form so when any one sends some feedback it should check the php of validation of it and send a email at the same time once the submit button is clicked. But I tested that but when I clicked the submit button it came up as an error page. Can any one please help me?

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_server['php_self']);?>
    , mailto:example@gmail.com" method="post" name="feedbackForm" id="ff" class="feedback"> <label for="first">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="fname" class="namef" placeholder="First Name" required="required"/><span class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr;?>
    </span><br/>
    <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last" name="lname" class="namel" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"/><span class="error"><?php echo $lnameErr;?>
    </span><br/>
    <label for="mail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" class="u-email" placeholder="any email is fine!" required="required"/><span class="error"><?php echo 
    $emailErr;?>
    </span><br/>
    <label for="yearLevel">Year Level:</label>
    <select name="yearLevel" id="yearLevel" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
        <option>Year 8</option>
        <option>Year 9</option>
        <option>Year 10</option>
        <option>Year 11</option>
        <option>Year 12</option>
        <option>Uni Student</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for"comment">Comment:</label>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="userComment" rows="12" cols="" "55" ">
    </textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitFeed" id="subff" class="sub" onclick="ask()" style="margin-left:20%;"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//feedback form validation code
//start

//variables
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $yearleErr = $emailErr = "";
$firstName = $lastName = $comment = $yearLevel = $email = "";


//the function of validation
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "* Your first name is required!";
    } else {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $firstName)) {
            $fnameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed!";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lnameErr = "* Your last name is required!";
    } else {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $lastName)) {
            $lnameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed!";
        }
    }

    if(empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $comment = "* the comment box is required!";
    } else {
        $comment = test_input($_post["comment"]);
    }


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "* Your email is required!";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
           $emailErr = "* Invalid Email Format!";
        }
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
//end
?>
```

JS script for a confirm when the user clicks submit. so it makes sense to the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//confrim before submitting.
function ask() {
    var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to send this feeback? If yes 
that you are sure click ok or if not then click canel to edit it.");
    if (box == true) {
        document.getElementById('firstPart').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('nextPart').style.display = "block";
        console.log("Thanks for sending your feedback");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("edit!");
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: No you cannot give multiple url's if you want to send mail means you can do that in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't add multiple actions in the form action, You should send the form to a PHP file and then after validating, send the email by PHP [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function or other libraries like PHPmailer etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No, you cannot add multiple actions for  tag, how you would the distinguish between which one to choose?

If you need to select different actions according to some configuration on form choices (or whatever), use *Javascript* to set new action of form.

In your case, use `mail` PHP function to send mail from PHP script when you pass your validation.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" name="feedbackForm" id="ff" class="feedback">
```

and then in PHP

```
mail('somebody@example.com', 'Subject', 'Body', optionalHeaders);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, but you can call `mailto` inside your `ask()` like,

```
function ask() {
    var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to send this feeback? If yes 
that you are sure click ok or if not then click canel to edit it.");
    if (box == true) {
        document.getElementById('firstPart').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('nextPart').style.display = "block";
        console.log("Thanks for sending your feedback");
        // add mailto here
        myWindow=window.open("mailto:example@gmail.com");
        myWindow.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("edit!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And change form action like,

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" ...>
  ....
</form>
```